# Android: is ContentResolver instance thread-safe?

Tags: android, multithreading, thread-safety, android-contentresolver

We all know that `ContentResolver` queries shouldn't be executed on UI thread, but, surprisingly, I can't find information about thread-safety of `ContentResolver` class in the official docs.

I know how to write thread-safe `ContentProvider`, and I know that `SQLite` is thread safe by default (it implements internal locking mechanism).

But, is it safe to use a single instance of `ContentResolver` from multiple threads (e.g. two treads call `insert()` or `query()` on the same object in parallel)?

Comment: I think you must have moved on, but for people who land up here it all depends on the underlying backing store, came across this wonderful article on the same
http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/10/sqlite-contentprovider-thread-safety.html

Comment: @humblerookie, the article is correct - SQLite implements internal locking, therefore implementations of `ContentProvider` backed by SQLite are thread safe. However, my question concerns `ContentResolver` and not `ContentProvider` -  is `ContentResolver` objects returned by `getContentResolver()` calls are thread safe. While these questions seem similar, they are really two completely different questions.

Comment: Apologies for being ignorant :/ .

However Just decided to take a look at the Content resolver object created by android. Seems like its an instance of ApplicationContentResolver
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/56a2301/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java

 As one can observe this class does not maintain state variables. So seems like the resolver object is indeed thread safe.

Comment: @humblerookie, if you have already investigated the source, why not publishing your findings as an answer?

Comment: Surely. Will do

Answer (score 4):

Digging a little into the source code we end up finding the ContentResolver instance created by android for an application being an instance of 
[`ApplicationContentResolver`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/56a2301/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java) class residing inside `ContentImpl`.

As one can see from the snippet below and the source of ContextResolver there are no state variables.

```
 private static final class ApplicationContentResolver extends ContentResolver {
        private final ActivityThread mMainThread;
        private final UserHandle mUser;
        public ApplicationContentResolver(
                Context context, ActivityThread mainThread, UserHandle user) {
            super(context);
            mMainThread = Preconditions.checkNotNull(mainThread);
            mUser = Preconditions.checkNotNull(user);
        }
    ....
```

This would imply necessarily that its thread safe.

Answer (score -1):

It depend on your code ,if you implment your contentResolver in the safe single instance that may be safe if you didn't add the lock ,it will not thread safe.